# How to restore server's connection while doing some network setting wrong?

Tags: remote-access

I do server setting from remote usually, but sometimes things went wrong, the server can't be connected from network anymore.

I've been disconnected from server with ip changing, firewall setting, bridge setting, etc.
Every time I need to restore the server locally or ask someone who can do it locally.

I also write little script to restore server's connection, but sometimes the script also went wrong.

Any good idea that can help me avoid server disconnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always have iLO/DRAC/ILOM configured. This is only way how to connect to server when things goes really bad.

Comment: iLO and the likes are life-savers, however, where I worked they ignored my requests for enabling iLO. So one day I had to change a route of a very remote server, it just hung. Luckily that machine had several NICs with different IPs/subnets configured, so I could log in on those and repair the primary NIC/IP-route.

Answer (score 1):

For firewall changes, I often set an `at` job to run five minutes into the future, to turn the firewall off, eg with

```
# at now+5min
at> /sbin/service iptables stop
^D
```

That way if the change I activate locks me out, I know in five minutes I'll be able to get back in.  If the change goes fine, I can remove the job with `atrm`.

Comment: Similar advice works great on switches - set them to reboot in [x] minutes ('reload in x' on Cisco for example). If it breaks then it should revert to the previous config.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the OS?
If it's a linux based -
Then you should have a console at your host company, or through your vmware which allows you to connect to your server even though network interfaces are down.

connect using the console
then:

choose the appropriate interface (i'll use eth0):
ethtool eth0 up

check you IP address and nic configuration:
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

restart your nics:
service network restart

then restart the machine with:
reboot